# Omniauth Authentication Failure Callback Handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, omniauth

I am using [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) and [omniauth-identity](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity) for authentication via Google, Facebook, and traditional username/password. I have it all pretty much working nicely except for the case where authentication fails. Upon failure, for example, when entering an invalid password, omniauth will call `/auth/failure`. I've mapped this to a controller which redirects to an appropriate page and presents a flash message. The problem I have is I cannot get the flash to actually display. Example code:

In `routes.rb`:

```
match "/auth/failure" => "sessions#failure"
```

In the controller it calls:

```
def failure
  redirect_to root_url, alert: "Authentication failed, please try again."
end
```

I feel the flash is being lost due to the combination of whatever omniauth is doing and the redirect. I know the view code is correct because it will flash other things, like a successful login message. I would appreciate suggestions on how to tweak my example to get the flash message to show, or suggestions for an alternate omniauth failure handling mechanism. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I have a same issue in my last project. It's a bug. Add following monkey patch to your config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
  # Omniauth failure monkey patch
  on_failure do |env|
    message_key = env['omniauth.error.type']
    origin_query_param = env['omniauth.origin'] ? "&origin=#{CGI.escape(env['omniauth.origin'])}" : ""
    strategy_name_query_param = env['omniauth.error.strategy'] ? "&strategy=#{env['omniauth.error.strategy'].name}" : ""
    extra_params = env['omniauth.params'] ? "&#{env['omniauth.params'].to_query}" : ""
    new_path = "#{env['SCRIPT_NAME']}#{OmniAuth.config.path_prefix}/failure?message=#{message_key}#{origin_query_param}#{strategy_name_query_param}#{extra_params}"
    Rack::Response.new(["302 Moved"], 302, 'Location' => new_path).finish
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I am misunderstanding how to apply this, but it appears to be no different in behavior from what I currently have (`redirect_after_failure` from the [omniauth FAQ](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/FAQ)) - no flash messages.